# ContextMenuOpening内で原因となったContextMenuを区別したい

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

ListBoxとListBoxItemにそれぞれContextMenuを設定し、項目と項目外で別のコンテキストメニューを開くようにしています。

このとき、ListBoxItemのコンテキストメニューを開いたときにListBoxのContextMenuOpeningイベントも同時に呼ばれてしまいます。
イベント内でどのContextMenuが開かれたのかを区別する方法はありますでしょうか。

#### 再現コード

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenuTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContextMenuTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ContextMenuOpening="ListBox_ContextMenuOpening">

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <EventSetter Event="ContextMenuOpening" Handler="ListBoxItem_ContextMenuOpening" />
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="ItemMenu" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="ListBoxMenu" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ContextMenuTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public string[] Items { get; } = new string[]
        {
            "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"
        };

        private void ListBox_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            // ここで区別したい
            Debug.WriteLine($"ListBox: ContextMenuOpening: {e.Source}");
        }

        private void ListBoxItem_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"ListBoxItem: ContextMenuOpening: {e.Source}");
        }
    }  
}
```

- Windows 10
- .NET Framework 4.7.2

#### 詳細

項目AAAを右クリックしてコンテキストメニューを開いたときのデバッグ出力

```
ListBoxItem: ContextMenuOpening: System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter
ListBox: ContextMenuOpening: System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:3
```

ListBoxの項目外(CCCの下の空白部分)を右クリックしてコンテキストメニューを開いたときのデバッグ出力

```
ListBox: ContextMenuOpening: System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:3
```

このように項目のコンテキストメニューを開いた場合でもListBox_ContextMenuOpeningが呼ばれてしまい、かつe.Sourceが同じなのでどちらのコンテキストメニューを開いたときのイベントなのか区別できません。

Comment: そもそもイベントのバブルを止めればイベントが二つ発生することはなくなると思いますが、二つのイベントを発生させた上で区別する必要があるのですか？

Comment: ListBoxItemのContextMenuOpeningで`e.Handled=true`にするとコンテキストメニュー自体が表示されなくなってしまうため、バブルを止められません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListBoxItemのContextMenuOpeningから直接ContextMenuを開きつつe.Handled=trueでルーティングイベントを停止することでListBox側のイベントが呼ばれることを回避しました。

```cs
private void ListBoxItem_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"ListBoxItem: ContextMenuOpening: {e.Source}");

    if (sender is FrameworkElement element && element.ContextMenu != null)
    {
        element.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

以下の様な感じで`sender`を`ListBox`でキャストすると、情報が取れます。
`SelectedIndex`は 0～2, `SelectedItem`と`SelectedValue`は同じ値で "AAA"/"BBB"/"CCC" でした。

```
private void ListBox_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    // ここで区別したい
    Debug.WriteLine($"ListBox: ContextMenuOpening: {e.Source}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"  SelectedIndex: {((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex }");
    Debug.WriteLine($"  SelectedItem : {((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem }");
    Debug.WriteLine($"  SelectedValue: {((ListBox)sender).SelectedValue }");
}
```

---

> ListBoxの項目外(CCCの下の空白部分)を右クリックしてコンテキストメニューを開いたときのデバッグ出力
>
> このように項目のコンテキストメニューを開いた場合でもListBox_ContextMenuOpeningが呼ばれてしまい、かつe.Sourceが同じなのでどちらのコンテキストメニューを開いたときのイベントなのか区別できません。

この場合、何かメニューの処理が終わったタイミング等で、以下の様な選択状態を解除する処理を入れてみてはどうでしょう？ 
例えばこんな感じでXAMLに`ContextMenuClosing`イベント処理を登録して、

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         ContextMenuOpening="ListBox_ContextMenuOpening"
         ContextMenuClosing="ListBox_ContextMenuClosing">
```

以下のように選択解除処理を行ったら、その次の項目外クリックで `SelectedIndex`が -1, `SelectedItem`と`SelectedValue`が空文字列で通知されました。

```
private void ListBox_ContextMenuClosing(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;
    ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem = "";
    ((ListBox)sender).SelectedValue = "";
}
```

他には中身を確認していませんが、こんな対処があるようです。
[yoshikazuendo/ListBoxSelectUnSelectSample.xaml](https://gist.github.com/yoshikazuendo/0115ebaabf5868c0dc78)

> 【WPF】単一選択のListBoxで選択解除の機能をBehaviorで実装してみた。
>   ※参考サイト
>   [ListBox with single select and also unselect on click…?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5139956/9014308)
>   [WPF “ビヘイビア” なるもの](https://tocsworld.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/wpf-%E3%83%93%E3%83%98%E3%82%A4%E3%83%93%E3%82%A2-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE/)

---

ちなみに以下は複数選択モードの場合の処理なので使えませんでした。

[Visual Studio / WPF > ListBoxの選択を解除する > 自作クラスのbfSelected プロパティ=falseではListBoxのSelectedItemsが残ったまま](https://qiita.com/7of9/items/7b2847e8f0bbe8084b8a)

> ```
> private void B_clearClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
> {
>     var myList = (this.DataContext as MyDataList);
>     // 1. 以下ではListBoxの選択状態が残ったままになった
>     //foreach (var elem in myList)
>     //{
>     //    elem.bfSelected = false;
>     //}
>     //myList.UpdateSelectedItems();
>
>     // 2. 以下ではListBoxの選択状態がクリアされる
>     listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();
>     myList.UpdateSelectedItems();
> }
> ```
>
> 上記において1の処理ではDataContextのmyList要素のbfSelectedはfalseになり、右側のListBoxの表示はクリアされた。
>   一方で、左側のlistBox1のSelectedItemsは残ったままだった。
>   (次回選択時に残っていたSelectedItemsも選択状態になった。)
>
> 2の処理ではlistBox1のSelectedItemsもクリアされた。
>   listBox1を直接指定している点はいいのかどうか。Bindingだけで処理できる方が良いようには思う。

Comment: 質問がわかりにくくて申し訳ありません。選ばれている項目でなく、どのコンテキストメニューが開かれたかを識別したいのです。例えば、項目AAAのコンテキストメニューを開いたあと、項目のない部分を右クリックしてListBoxのコンテキストメニューを開くと同じ情報になり、どちらのコンテキストメニューをひらいたことによるイベントなのか区別できなくなります。

Comment: どんな感じなのかスクリーンショットでも載せてもらえますか？ あるいはXAMLのソースを全て記述するとか？ 単に新規プロジェクトを作って質問のソースを追加しただけのプログラムとは動きが違うようですので。

Comment: 質問の詳細を追記しコードを完全にしました。

Comment: 起動直後ではSelectedIndexは-1になるのですが、「項目AAAのコンテキストメニューを開いたあと」では項目外のコンテキストメニューを開いてもListBoxの状態に変化はなく、SelectedIndexは0になってしまいます。